# awk failed in subsetting in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a massive tab separated file that I am working with, I was trying to subset a table depending on the availability of a string 'car' in the 45th column. This is what the file looks like

```
col1    col2   ...   col44    col45

JPO     JIO    ...    JKU     car
JKO     LIC    ...    YHI     car/kcar
KJG     KLE    ...    HIY     tm/car/kcar
```

I applied the following command to do the subsetting

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $45 ~ /^car$/ '  filepath | wc
```

I get that there is 90 rows as "car" in the file, although I previously know (from viewing the file in excel) that more than 1500 row has their `col45` as `car`.

Any idea what's going on here??

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know `awk`, but there i̶s̶  was`4` in your command, not `45`. Also, you mixed up `^` and `$`. `$` means end, `^` beginning (at least in all regex engines I know).

Comment: Which of the 3 sample rows do you want in your output? Do you want `$45 == "car"`? Do you want $45 contains the *word* car: `$45 ~ /\<car\>/`? Do you want $45 contains the characters car: `$45 ~ /car/`?

Comment: sorry I thought of making a simple question then I decided to ask about the original case, it is column 45. And I still get 90 as a result. Thanks for the correction

Comment: I want only the first one, that's why I looked up /^car$/ (I might need to do more later, But I cannot understand what went wrong here! it is a very simple task!!)

Comment: Try `$45 == "car"` -- that works with IGNORECASE. But that should be the same as what you have. Are you sure in your assertion that you're missing some records?

Comment: Are any of `col1`..`col44` ever empty (i.e. subsequent tab characters that would be considered a single separator), especially on the `1500-90=1410` rows that are not being matched?

Comment: I have just tried "awk '{if ($35 == "car") print $0;}' /filepath | wc"  and I still get 90! I downloaded the file from my virtual Linux machine to windows and opened it in excel and I have over 1500 rows as "car". :S

Comment: twalberg has a good idea. Try `awk -F'\t' '$45=="car"'`. Or, if $45 is the *last* column: `awk '$NF=="car"'`

Comment: Ok guys! well I get 1578 now, although they are 1581 :) But that's (sort of) solved the problem. I don't want to be greedy but... and ideas how to get the remaining 3 rows? :D

Comment: How about `cut -f45 < file | grep -c`? If a cell (row,column) is empty, it should still work.

Comment: @anishsane. Yep, gave me the right number, same as twalberg's command. cheers all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work well in gawk (my regular awk does not have `IGNORECASE`):

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN { IGNORECASE = 1; FS = "\t"; }
$2 ~ /^car/
$ cat foo.inp
l1  notcar
l2  CAR/blah
l3  car
$ gawk -f foo.awk < foo.inp
l2  CAR/blah
l3  car
$
```

(I used $2 rather than $45, and I assumed you wanted things that *start with* car, not "are exactly equal to" car.)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer actually captured the 3 missing rows that escaped the above answers (in the comments). cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate option:

```
cut -f45 < file | grep -c '^car' #OR
cut -f45 < file | grep -c -i '^car'
```

It should work even if there is an empty cell.